# VBA Join Ranges

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

So I have a constant 7 number of ranges which are all one cell wide and a large, arbitrary height which is the same between them.  Is it possible to join the ranges so that I have one range that only consists of all 7 ranges? I have tried the UnionRange function but it returns numbers far larger than to be expected.

This is what I have so far:

```
' acquire the range of each column, using its coumn number and the user-defined Col_Letter function
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = Sheets("sheet_name").Range(Col_Letter(col_1) & ":" & Col_Letter(col_1) & LRow)
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 = Sheets("sheet_name").Range(Col_Letter(col_2) & ":" & Col_Letter(col_2) & LRow)
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Set rng3 = Sheets("sheet_name").Range(Col_Letter(col_3) & ":" & Col_Letter(col_3) & LRow)
    Dim rng4 As Range
    Set rng4 = Sheets("sheet_name").Range(Col_Letter(col_4) & ":" & Col_Letter(col_4) & LRow)
    Dim rng5 As Range
    Set rng5 = Sheets("sheet_name").Range(Col_Letter(col_5) & ":" & Col_Letter(col_5) & LRow)
    Dim rng6 As Range
    Set rng6 = Sheets("sheet_name").Range(Col_Letter(col_6) & ":" & Col_Letter(col_6) & LRow)
    Dim rng7 As Range
    Set rng7 = Sheets("sheet_name").Range(Col_Letter(col_7) & ":" & Col_Letter(col_7) & LRow)

    ' Join the ranges of each column into one range
    Dim UnionRange As Range
    Set UnionRange = Union(rng1, rng2, rng3, rng4, rng5, rng6, rng7)
    Debug.Print "Width of UnionRange: " & UnionRange.width
    Debug.Print "Height of UnionRange: " & UnionRange.height
```

Comment: Reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you get an answer sooner. Remember, this isn't a code-writing service, so post what you've got & we can help you fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice; I posted my code.  However, I asked if it was possible.  I never told anybody to write code for me.  Even a reference to a built in function or way of approaching the problem would have been more than I asked.

Comment: After you `Set rng1 = ...` do a `rng1.select`. It looks to me like you're missing your row from the left-hand side of your range.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? To be honest since you might as well copy all the data into why Worksheet and then work on ranges...

Comment: Once you get all your ranges on one sheet (as mentioned by [Gary](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30375395/2344413)) Your `UnionRange.Width` will be `Max(Col_1...Col7) - Min(Col_1...Col7)`. That may account for a larger number than you are expecting

Comment: @Data.life It's so that I can work on the data only in a certain region.  After that I turn the data into a collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run *UNION()* on ranges from different worksheets.  A *Range* is limited to a set of cells on a single sheet.

**EDIT#1:**

I suspect your Debug.Print.  Your are printing a **pixel**-related variable rather than a **row count**

```
Sub dural()
   Dim r As Range
   Set r = Range("A1:C5")
   MsgBox r.Height & vbCrLf & r.Rows.Count
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: My bad, I'll edit the question.  I renamed the sheets for simplicity but they actually have the same name.

Comment: When I did this, using the location of the actual row, the row height was the correct value! However, when I did this using my rng1 variable, I got a different height

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Now I know that I can use Union and can solve it from here.

Comment: @Paradox, if you manage to solve it, do come back and post your answer. That will be of help to others.

Answer (score 1):

Try using unionrange.rows.count and unionrange.columns.count instead its is possible that width and height uses difference between border cell addresses instead of counting it

Comment: I did as you suggested and the column count was perfect yet the row count was several times larger than expected.

Comment: what if you manually count the difference between first row number and the last? does it match the output number of rows?

Comment: I suspect it is a problem with when I set the range

Comment: Possible, you are specifying the start of range by Col_Letter(col_7) without any numer next to it, but the end has additional LROW, you should add the proper start row of range after col_letter just like u did in case of range end with LROW by adding FirstRow for example

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by acquiring the row number bounds like so:

```
Dim FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long    
With Get_Workbook.Sheets("Sheet_Name").UsedRange
     FirstRow = .Row
     LastRow = .Rows(UBound(.Value)).Row
End With
```

From there, I modified my code to this format:

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Get_Workbook.Sheets("Sheet_Name").Range(Col_Letter(col_1) & FirstRow & ":" & Col_Letter(col_1) & LastRow)
```

This way, I have already found the correct column letter with my Col_Letter function and I can get the correct, used range as well.

Note that Get_Workbook and Col_Letter are user-defined functions.